# Creation of the helper (Helper) in Zend Framework 3 (Is impossible)

Tags: zend-framework3

I am create class in /module/Application/src/View/Helper/Messages

Code:

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Messages extends AbstractHelper { 
public function __construct() {   
}   
protected function renderErrorMessages($item) {
        echo "!!!";
}

}
```

Add his in module.config.php
Code:

```
  ....
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,                       
            Controller\UserController::class => InvokableFactory::class,                       
        ],
    ],
    'view_helpers' => [
            'factories' => [
                View\Helper\Messages::class => InvokableFactory::class,                   
            ],
           'aliases' => [
                'messages' => View\Helper\Messages::class
           ]
        ],                   
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
```

On page login.phtml i am insert code:

```
...
<?php echo $this->Messages()->renderErrorMessages(); ?>
...
```

And get in log error:

> [Wed Mar 13 12:18:30.725622 2019] [php7:error] [pid 9697] [client
>   127.0.0.1:52914] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: A plugin by
>   the name "Messages" was not found in the plugin manager
>   Zend\View\HelperPluginManager in
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:142\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(376):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Messages', NULL)\n#1
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(394):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('Messages')\n#2
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/module/Application/view/layout/login.phtml(32):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('Messages', Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(506):
>   include('/var/www/webuse...')\n#4
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(207):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(NULL)\n#5
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrateg
>   in
>   /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php
>   on line 142, referer: http://127.0.0.128/user/login
>       1

What do I do not so?

Comment: what do you want to do? to create your own custom view helper? or to use existing for error messages?? you are registering "messages" and you call $this->Messages with an upper case then you call renderErrorMessages() without argument but in the class function, you have argument $item. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Update view-helper configuration with Full qualified class name.

```
'view_helpers' => [
                'factories' => [
                    Application\View\Helper\Messages::class => InvokableFactory::class,                   
                ],
               'aliases' => [
                    'messages' => Application\View\Helper\Messages::class
               ]
            ],
```

And On page login.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->messages()->renderErrorMessages($item); ?>
```

...